# How to add buttons in list view in OpenERP

Tags: openerp-7

How to add buttons in list view.

As mention in below fig[image]

i need to add two buttons. how to add it under list view. in the place i have marked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't add any buttons there,you can only add buttons in form view